# Filter the co-workers who are working right now

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I've got a table called Work and the columns are

```
EmployeeID(key), 
Date (datetime, when the employee checked in to work),
Work hours (int, the hours he/she will be working for)
```

This is a school project, so I can't modify the tables at all.
I have to write a select which gives back the ones who are working in that moment, this is what I got so far:

```
select EmployeeID as Availables, w.Date as Started at
from Work w
where datepart(year,w.Date) = DATEPART(year,getdate()) and 
datepart(month,w.Datum) = datepart(month,getdate()) and
datepart(day,w.Date) = datepart(day,getdate()) and
datepart(hour,w.Date) <= datepart(hour,getdate()) and
datepart(hour,w.Date)+w.WorkHours > datepart(hour,getdate())
```

This solution isn't right, since if I run the query at 01:00 AM, and the employee started the work on the previous day at 23:00 PM (which is possible), then he won't be on the list. 
I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Do you have checked out time if he stop his working ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I've only got the hours of his shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the logic of finding the currently working employees

```
select EmployeeID as Availables, w.Date as Started at
from Work w where getdate() between w.Date and DATEADD(HOUR, w.WorkHours,  w.Date)
```

Comment: Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: @h2c If the w.Date is not a datetime field then you should convert it to datetime object

Comment: It is a datetime field.

Comment: @h2c I changed my query. Please recheck

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
select EmployeeID as Availables, w.Date as Started at
from Work w where w.Date>= DATEADD(HH,  w.WorkHours,w.Date,) and  w.Date<=getdate()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the dateadd function still responds with the same error: Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.